# Local development of client and services against API Gateway

Tags: api-gateway

When developing backend microservices that sit behind an API Gateway how do you develop locally, ensuring that client requests to a single endpoint (the API gateway) and request path are routed to the right local service?

The Microsoft [eShopOnContainers](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers) architecture example uses Envoy as a local API Gateway (it used to be Ocelot) but how would you then deploy a stack like this to the cloud, keeping your local and cloud API Gateways in sync with the right request routing, resource descriptions, etc? Do you essentially need to manage two API gateway configurations?

I'm aware of SAM and `sam local start-api` but I'm referring to other backend services that aren't serverless, e.g. using `VpcLink`.